# Unable to run file from command line after adding to PATH

Tags: bash, shell-script, path, function

So I have a function that I wish to run from my command line.

```
cat foo.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo foobar
```

I export it to my PATH variable and change to a different directory.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/usr/scripts/foo.sh

mkdir test && cd test
sh foo.sh
sh: foo.sh: No such file or directory
```

If i run it like so `foo.sh` I get `bash: foo.sh: command not found`.

I could run it  with the absolute path, but I didn't think I would need to if I added it to my $PATH. What mistake am I making here?

Thanks.

Comment: `PATH` should contain *paths*, not files i.e. `PATH=${PATH}:/home/usr/scripts`

Comment: Note that `sh foo.sh` in a different directory still won't work even if you fix the PATH, this tells `sh` to run the file `foo.sh` in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues here. The `$PATH` consists of colon-separated directories, not files. You shouldn't declare a script as a `bash` script and then use `sh` to run it. Generally speaking, a file that you're going to call as if it were a standard utility wouldn't have an extension. (Extensions are optional in many situations anyway.)

```
# Create a directory
mkdir -p "$HOME/bin"

# Create a script in that directory
cat <<'EOF' >"$HOME/bin/myscript"    # Don't use "test" :-O
#!/bin/bash
echo This is myscript
EOF

# Make it executable
chmod a+x "$HOME/bin/myscript"

# Add the directory to the PATH
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"

# Now run the script as if it's a normal command
myscript
```

The caution against using a script called `test` is that `/bin/test` already exists as a valid command. Furthermore, in many shells `test` is a built-in that will override your own script regardless of the directory order in `$PATH`.